# Form post action: not seeing query parameters in $_POST

Tags: php, http

I have a small PHP application (MVC) with a form. The action looks something like this:

```
<form action="<?php sprintf("/v/.../update?job=%s", $job->id);?>" method="post">
```

Here `$job` is a PHP object I pass the view from the controller. I hold onto the `id` field (an integer) so that I can update the row in the database corresponding to the object.

I'm not seeing this value in `$_POST` (it is in `$GET`, though) when I step into my `update` function for a post request. How should I retrieve this value? Is this expected?

Comment: you are sending 'job' as get not post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get by $_GET['job'] or remove 'job' from action url and send in hidden text field to get as $_POST['job'].

Also I think your action url is not creating. use echo

```
<form action="<?php echo sprintf("/v/.../update?job=%s", $job->id);?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

you pass your job param as url string, and in this case it can be seen in `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` arraies not `$_POST` whatever your form action get or post, because this param isn't form input.